# Change bootstrap button class

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the text and colour of buttons when execute onclick event.
The text is changed correctly but with the color have some problems.

With this line put some dynamically buttons:

```
$register_status = '<button class="btn btn-success btn_status btn-block" data-status="Active">Active</button>';

$register_status = '<button class="btn btn-warning btn_status btn-block" data-status="Inactive">Inactive</button>';
```

and with this jquery can change the text but the last line can't run correctly.

```
$('body').click('.btn_status', function(e){
var button = jQuery(e.target);
if(button.data('status') == 'Active'){
          button.data('status', 'Inactive');
          button.html('Inactive');
          $(".btn_status").removeClass("btn-warning").addClass("btn-success");
        }else if(button.data('status') == 'Inactive'){
...
```

what's wrong? thanks.

Comment: I reverted your last edit because it fundamentally changed the question. Two answers here provided solutions as it was originally written. Please respond to them appropriately, and post a new question if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML snippet has your class as `btn_status` but your selector is looking for `btnstatus`. Notice the missing underscore in your selector.

Also, don't use a new selector if you already have a variable for the button (`button`) as you may be selecting a different element.

Change 
`$(".btn_status").removeClass("btn-warning").addClass("btn-success");`
to
`button.removeClass("btn-warning").addClass("btn-success");` just like you're using for the call to `.html(..)`

Comment: good view! but I change and can't change the class ```$(".btn_status").removeClass("btn-warning").addClass("btn-success");
```

Comment: I put this code but all buttons change the color when I click. I need only change the button that I press

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you're targeting the clicked element with everything but your class toggler (where you're targeting *all* elements with the class `btn_status`). Use it there also and it all works fine.

```
var button = jQuery(e.target);

if (button.data('status') == 'Active') {
    button.data('status', 'Inactive');
    button.html('Inactive');
    button.toggleClass("btn-warning btn-success");
} else {
    button.data('status', 'Active');
    button.html('Active');
    button.toggleClass("btn-warning btn-success");
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9ukvbrmL/)**

**[Demo with chaining](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9ukvbrmL/2/)**

Comment: I put this code but all buttons change the color when I click. I need only change the button that I press

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect help when I can't see what you've done. Clearly the demo works. Figure out how your implementation is different.